# How to make javascript work along with Ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, validation, updatepanel

I am trying to add validation on my form. I am using AJAX controls in my form fields.
When I remove the Update panel and AJAX control, my validation starts working, but when keeping both the things together, my validation is not working. How could I make them work together?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Validate() {
        var QuestionTextArea = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphBody_midbox_fvInsert_txtQuestion");

        varError = "";
        if (!IsTextBoxEmpty(QuestionTextArea, "\nQuestion Text Area  not be Empty.")) {
            alert(varError);
            document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphBody_midbox_fvInsert_txtQuestion").focus();
            return false;
        } return true;
    }
</script>



    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

             <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" MaxLength="1000" Columns="50" Rows="5" Style="width: 380px;
             float: none" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" />
             <AjaxControl:TextBoxWatermarkExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtQuestion"
              WatermarkCssClass="water" WatermarkText="Type your Question Here.">
             </AjaxControl:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>


           </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I removes ajax extender and Update Panel. My textbox gets validated and when using UpdatePanel. No javascript function created by me is called.

Comment: It would be simpler for us to answer your question when you post relevant parts of your source.

Answer (score 1):

> An **UpdatePanel completely replaces the contents of the update panel on
>   an update**.
>   This means that those events you subscribed to are no
>   longer subscribed because there are new elements in that update panel.
>   Full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels/256253#256253)

In your Page or MasterPage, put the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

  function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
  {
    Validate(); 
  }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A well known issue with the first version of the ajax extensions was to break validators. ScottGu even blogged about the solution to add the folowing nodes under `<system.web><controls><pages>` in your web.config:

```
<tagMapping>
   <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator" 
        mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CompareValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
   <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator" 
        mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CustomValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
   <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RangeValidator" 
        mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RangeValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
   <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator" 
        mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RegularExpressionValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
   <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator" 
        mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RequiredFieldValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
   <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary"
        mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.ValidationSummary, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
</tagMapping>
```